# How do I implement User Authentication using Salt Hashing in node js

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to implement salt Hashing for user registration in node js. User login needs to have access to stored salt value. but the challenge I have now is: How do I store the salt value securely ?

I'm also open to better implementation of the Authentication process. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an example you can follow
For Registration.

```
    import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

export const insertUserAsOwner = async (addOwnerDto) => {
    const tempPassword = generateRandomString(8);    
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(tempPassword, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10));
    const user = new Users();
    user.firstName = addOwnerDto.firstName;
    user.lastName = addOwnerDto.lastName;
    user.username = addOwnerDto.username;
    user.password = hashedPassword;
    user.typeOfUser = 'owner';
    user.business = business;
    const savedUser = await user.save();
}
```

For Login

```
import bcryptjs from 'bcryptjs';

const validate = async(password) =>{

const user = await Users.findOne({username: 'someusername'});
const hashedPassowrd = user.password;
    const isValid = await bcryptjs.compare(password, hashedPassword);
if(isValid) return true;    
return false
```

}

Comment: this does not save the salt and thus is insecure and also probably doesn't work (?)

Comment: No, nevermind, your solution is good, as bcrypt stores the salt inside the hash https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt